# SQL - Sum of minutes between two timestamps by month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am looking for an SQL query for the sum of minutes between start and end date for a particular month.

Eg.
I'm looking for the amount of minutes used in February.

Start Date Time:  27-02-13 00:00:00
End Date Time: 05-03-13 00:00:00

Because im only looking for the sum of february it should only give me the sum of 3 days (in minutes) and not the extra 5 days going into march.

Comment: Which RDBMS -- date/time functions are db specific.

Comment: I am using an odbc connection with the sql driver to an SQL Server 2008 r2 box.

Comment: I have tried using computed columns and summing the data, but when the data is flowing into the next month my sums are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no way to validate it but it should looks like:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, startDate, CASE when endDate > EOMONTH(startDate) THEN EOMONTH(startDate) ELSE endDate END) FROM ...
```

GL!

Comment: Thanks Eli, I didnt have the EOMONTH function to i substituted it as follows: SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, datetime5, CASE when datetime6 > dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,GetDate())+1, 0) THEN dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,GetDate())+1, 0) ELSE datetime6 END)AS TotalMinutes,0 FROM AllUserData

Comment: My only challenge is now, if someone creates an entry for lastmonth that includes minutes from this month how do i include them in my sum. :)

Comment: @Aaron keep track of the last ID you processed and process anything beyond that ID?  Not really sure what you're overall goal is so this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using `DATEDIFF` -- this will just help you to get started:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, starttime, endtime)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

To get the last day of the start month, use `DATEADD`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(second,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,starttime)+1,0))
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9211/3)

Comment: I already have the DATEDIFF part working fine, i can get the difference between the two columns. The part im struggling with is how to break it down by month.

Comment: @Aaron -- do you want to pass it a month as well and just return Feb?  Or are you looking into Grouping the months from the start/end times?

Comment: Yes im looking to pass it a month aswell and just return Feb.

Comment: @Aaron -- I edited my answer slightly -- same logic should work passing in a month.  DATEADD can get you the last day of the month, and DATEDIFF can get you the difference in time between those dates.  Good luck.

Comment: No, don't use this dateadd(second,-1) nonsense, please.

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- I guess you don't have to subtract the second, but I've used that method several times before and it works well: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/

Comment: @sgeddes maybe, until someone changes the underlying data type to `SMALLDATETIME`. `BETWEEN` is a terrible, terrible thing to suggest IMHO - open-ended range is much more reliable, e.g. `>= Feb1 AND < Mar1` won't break. Much more information [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) and [here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries). The subtracting a second or 3 milliseconds methods are dirty hacks that will eventually fail.

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- thanks for the information -- very good to read and makes rather complete sense.  Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I left it in steps to illustrate each process.  You can of course easily collapse this down, but I'll leave it up to you to do that.

Here's my solution http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4991/1/0

```
SELECT *
  , DATEDIFF(minute, StartDAte, NewEndDate) AS TotalMinutes
FROM
(
  SELECT *
    , CASE WHEN TempDate > EndDate THEN EndDate ELSE TempDate END AS NewEndDate -- Either EOM or old EndDate, whichever is smaller
  FROM
  (
    SELECT *
      , DATEADD(month, 1, CAST(Year + '-' + Month + '-1' AS DATETIME)) AS TempDate -- first day of the next month
    FROM
    (
      select *
       , CAST(DATEPART(month, StartDate) AS char(2)) AS Month
       , CAST(DATEPART(year, StartDate) AS char(4)) AS Year
      from tbl
    ) t0
  ) t1
) t2
```

First I get the year and month from the original `StartDate`. I then construct a first-of-the-month date from that.  I then add one month to that to get me the first-of-the-month of the next month.  Then I check if that new date is > or < the previous `EndDate`.  I take the smaller of the two dates.  Then I use the original `StartDate` and whichever is smaller between the `TempDate` and `EndDate` to determine my total minutes.

See Also EOMONTH: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx

Comment: @Aaron once you understand the basics of what my answer is showing, I'd consider going with http://stackoverflow.com/a/15113905/1795053 as your solution.  It is greatly simplified/compacted version that uses a built-in SQL function to get the EOMONTH date.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to solve a similar problem, I added two new functions to help with this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GREATESTDATE] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Date1 DATETIME,
    @Date2 DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN


    IF (@Date1 < @Date2)
        RETURN @Date2
    ELSE 
        RETURN @Date1

END
```

and...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LEASTDATE] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Date1 DATETIME,
    @Date2 DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    IF (@Date1 > @Date2)
        RETURN @Date2
    ELSE 
        RETURN @Date1

END
```

Then use them like:

```
DATEDIFF(D,dbo.GREATESTDATE(@StartDate1,@StartDate2),dbo.LEASTDATE(@EndDate1,@EndDate2))
```